# How to pass clearInterval from function to another function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I got my circle, it has setinterval() on each direction clicked.
The problem is when I click for the circle to go up and before it reaches to the top I press down and it stops mid air and if I press down again it goes to the bottom yet my half circle which turns to red doesn't appear because the circle is unable to reach to the bottom which is 300px, instead it stuck on 299px;

I'm looking for clearing the Interval of downFunc() if I press upFunc() before it reaches the bottom.

I'm a beginner in javascript and I know my code is not efficient, but how do I solve it?

https://jsbin.com/xuteqatela/edit?output

Comment: Is this what you are looking for [**fiddle**](https://jsbin.com/pasemujune/1/edit?output) ?

Comment: Just move your intervals into the global namespace like all the other variables so you can reference them in each function.

Comment: Post relevant code inside the question.

Comment: DavidDomain, exactly what I was looking for, ty guys.